# Convert comma separated two string values to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert comma separated two string values to SQL Server table.
Note: Key,value will always contain same length in both strings.

Example:

```
Key => Dev1,Dev2
Value=> Test1,Test2
```

Output should be in single table like below:

```
Column1      Column2
----------   ------
Dev1         Test1
Dev2         Test2
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: Is the spacing in your input file consistent? `Key =>` has a space, `Value=>` does not...

Comment: i am using MS SQL server 2019

Answer (score 1):

You need a splitter to parse the input strings into subtrings with their positions. One possible option is a JSON-based approach. You need to transform the comma-separated values into a JSON array and parse this array with `OPENJSON()` and default schema:

```
DECLARE @Key varchar(1000) = 'Dev1,Dev2,Dev3'
DECLARE @Value varchar(1000) = 'Test1,Test2,Test3'

SELECT 
   j1.[value] AS Column1,
   j2.[value] AS Column2
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(@Key, 'json'), ',', '","'), '"]')) j1
FULL JOIN OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(@Value, 'json'), ',', '","'), '"]')) j2
   ON j1.[key] = j2.[key]
```

Result:

```
Column1 Column2
---------------
Dev1    Test1
Dev2    Test2
Dev3    Test3
```

Comment: @HarsshGajjar . . . If this answers your question, you should consider accepting it.